# Como identificar o IP do usuário?

Tags: ip, redes, c++-cli

Como pegar o IP de rede de quem abrir meu programa? Estou usando a linguagem C++, Visual Studio 2013 e Windows Form, existe alguma função que faça isso?

Comment: Está bastante difícil entender seu problema. Pode explicar?

Comment: não estou conseguindo checar no banco de dados o IP, pois a variavel IP é char e o campo IP é varchar (string);

Comment: Se vc faz um "prinf" do IP, vc tem? O fato que o IP "em C" e um CHAR e o campo um VARCHAR não importa. Do ponto de vista de SQL vc ta procurando um "string" e para ele não importa se do lado di C o "string" a um char ou outra coisa. Uma coisa bem util e evitar colocar diretamente o query na chamada tipo "MySqlCommand("SELEC...". Melhor ter uma variavel com o query. Assim, e facil fazer um "printf" da variavel para verificar se o query esta coreto.

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: "A linha que da erro é essa". Que erro? Pode colocar exatamente a mensagem que você recebe (ou o comportamento inesperado que você vê)?

Comment: Eu descobri que esse método de pegar o ip está errado, ele retorna 11, eu já tentei diversas formas de pegar o ip do usuário e não consigo.

Comment: Me desculpe, mas essa última edição mudou completamente a pergunta. O que exatamente você quer saber? É consulta no banco de dados? É sobre conversão de variável? É sobre verificar IP atual da máquina? Não está claro.

Comment: Eu quero saber o IP da rede do usuário ex: 198.35.56.100 e depois fazer uma verificação no Banco de Dados (MySQL) pra saber se existe lá.

Comment: Então são duas perguntas separadas e pouco relacionadas. Vou editar essa para a primeira pergunta e depois crie outra pergunta para a consulta no MySQL

Comment: A parte do MySQL eu já tenho, só quero pegar o IP.